# Calling another table by using id flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Im new on flask and im wondering if its possible to call an item through item code like for example

```
items_name 

item_code    item_name
______________________
BOLT-001     BOLT 20mm
BOLT-002     BOLT 12mm
```

and out table like

```
items
item code   item qty
______________________
BOLT-001    20
```

how to print something like

> BOLT 20mm x 20pcs

in laravel it would be like

```
->join('items_name','items.item_code','items_name.item_code')
```

but how to do it in flask?

Comment: use join operation on both tables, and use item_code as join condition

Comment: @sahasrara62 so basically if there's like 8 tables that needs item_name, do i need to join the whole 8 of them?

Comment: Don't  know on that as ur schema is not aviable , but in this case use can write a query which join 2 tables

Comment: With `flask-sqlalchemy` your models should have an inherit `query` already mapped into the model class: `ItemsName.query.join(Items, ItemsName.item_code).all()` - you can add `filter` calls as needed. You might not need the explicit `ItemsName.item_code` either. Depending on your models, you can also configure this as something that is always retrieved through `relationship` with `lazy='joined'` - that way the relation will always be populated automagically when you retrieve an ItemName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've finally found the answer
it appears that i have to add

on items_name model:

```
any = db.relationship('items', backref='item_name', lazy=True)
```

and on items model :

```
item_code= db.Column(db.String,db.ForeignKey('item_name.name')
```